# Draw lines behind nodes in raphael

Tags: javascript, raphael

We are constructing a mind map through raphael Javascript library. Is there anyway to make the lines look behind the node, when the lines passed through a node.

Thanks in Advance.

Karthik.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty hard to guess what you are trying to achieve exactly, but I have some suggestions for you, that might work:

- first make sure that the node has a solid background
- second you can use [toFront](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.toFront) and [toBack](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.toBack) to pull objects to the front or push them to the background